# Dual axis: yticks scaling

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have a problem in fixing my `y ticks` when having a dual axis plot. The ticks on the second plot dont match the grid of the first. Is it possible to rescale the second plot in order to make only one grid work for both plots?

This is what my code looks like on the second `axis` environment.

```
\begin{axis}[
  scale only axis, % The height and width argument only apply to the actual axis
  height=6cm,
  width=12cm,
  yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/precision=0, /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill=true},
  scaled y ticks=true,
  axis y line*=right,
  axis x line=none,
  ylabel=Antenna Impedance ($\Omega$),
  ylabel near ticks
  ]
\end{axis}
```

[image: Dual axis - not fixed tikz axis]

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I need to scale the y ticks on the second plot to match the y ticks of the first thus making a global grid for both plots.

Comment: @user1373403: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @user1373403: You can always edit your own questions and answers, also with very low reputation, please add info from comment into question. And a suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if you turned your code into a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: @user1373403, there's no general way to solve this (because the two `axis` environments have no knowledge of each other). So we really need to see a complete MWE setting up the plots for any hope of an answer.